# Простой синтаксис if else&

Tags: java

Ребят, помогите расшифровать эту запись на java.

```
return name != null ? name.toUpperCase() : null;
```

Точнее как эта запись выглядит старым добрым if else.

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (name != null) {
    return name.toUpperCase();
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (name != null)
    return name.toUpperCase()
else 
    return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Это называется [тернарным оператором](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018)

```
if (name != null) {
    return name.toUpperCase();
}
return null;
```